# How to add response header to wso2 authentication endpoints

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, content-security-policy, response-headers, strict-transport-security

i'm able to add the response header to all my API except for the wso2 authentication endpoints

https://testorsampletdomain.com/oauth2/authorize

https://testorsampletdomain.com/authenticationendpoint/login.do?

https://testorsampletdomain.com/logincontext?

I need to add strict-transport-security and content-security-policy to response header of authentication endpoints pls help to address the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the custom header filter in the identity server by following the guide here
https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-carbon-auth-rest#custom-header-filter
NOTE: This filter is available after IS-5.11.0 https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/9088

When comes to step 4 of the guide:
The custom response headers that you want to add;

- for the authentication endpoint responses should be added under the application name "authenticationendpoint"
- for the oauth2 endpoint responses should be added under the application name "oauth2"

Answer (score 0):

How about exposing these endpoints via APIM as APIs? This way you can add a mediation policy to add these headers?

Comment: apim uses 8243 port as default which is needed for other apis and cant be added for authentication endpoints

Comment: You can configure port offset and avoid any clashes between already ports in use - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/deploy-api/deploy-through-multiple-api-gateways/#step-21-configure-port-offset